# What is the probability that there are more than $50\%$ of those customers who responded the messages?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

The percentage of customers who respond to a company's messages is $20\%.$ In the past week, that company sent messages to $400$ customers. What is the probability that there are more than $50\%$ of those customers who responded the messages ?

It is not stated but we must assume that customer responses are independent (otherwise there is no solution). In that case, the probability is basically $\sum_{k= 201}^{400}\!\left ( 0.2 \right)^{k}\!\left ( 0.8 \right )^{400- k}\!\binom{400}{k}\!\cong 0.$ The intuition is that the distribution is very nearly normal with mean $400\cdot\frac{1}{5}= 80$ and standard deviation $\!\sqrt{400\!(1-\!\frac{1}{5})\!\frac{1}{5}}\!= 8,$ so having more than $200$ responses is a more than $15$ standard deviation event!
Is this right ??

Comment: You could use a binomial distribution, but on the face of it the answer will be very close to $0$, perhaps between $10^{-41}$ and $10^{-40}$  if responses are independent

Comment: This: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: You want $P(X \ge 200)$ for $X\sim\mathsf{Binom}(400, 0.2).$ In R, binomial probability is $\approx 0.$ You could use normal aprx with $\mu = 80, \sigma = 8.$ (But 200 is many std deviations above the mean. Purpose of problem may be to see if you know what to do when z score is way beyond tabled values.) Not a particularly good situation for a Poisson approximation, but the question is so extreme that Poisson also happens to give $\approx 0.$